# Sending Tweet data to PUG template from within GET method

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

What's the most efficient way to send data fetched from within a GET function to a PUG template? I've been pushing the data into an array and then sending that to the template, but this seems inefficient.

```
app.get('/tweet/:id', function(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id;
    T.get('statuses/show/' + id, function(err, data, response) {
        let stweet = [];
        stweet.push(data.text);
    });
    res.render('tweet', {stweet: stweet});
});
```

This gets a Tweet ID from the url and uses it to retrieve the Tweet object. Is there some way I can pull "data" from `T.get('statuses/show'...)` and display it directly on the PUG template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code cannot possible work, since `T.get` is asyncrhonous & `stweet` is defined in a scope which `res.render('tweet', {stweet: stweet});` does not have access. So that code will throw:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stweet is not defined
```

`T` supports promises, you should use them so your code would be a lot cleaner. After `T.get` is done just send the data directly to the PUG template, there is no need to use: `.push`

```
app.get('/tweet/:id', async(req, res) => {

    try {
        // We wait until `T.get` is done
        const { data } = await T.get(`statuses/show/${req.params.id}`, { /** params **/ });    
        res.render('tweet', { stweet: [data.text] });

    } catch(e) {
        // Or whatever error message you want to display
        res.render('error'); 
    }
});
```

You should check: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Comment: This seems to always return the error. I can't figure out why that happening.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'base' or undefined". It seems that adding an empty config object gets me around the issue, though. `const { data } = await T.get('statuses/show/' + req.params.id, {});` Thank You!